# PDO PHP - Find all rows between 2 dates - shows blank

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, between

Using PDO php i am trying to get all the rows in my database tables that have a start_date within the current week. To calculate the first and last date of this week i use the following:

```
$week_start = date('d-m-Y',time()+( 1 - date('w'))*24*3600);  
$week_end =  date('d-m-Y',time()+( 7 - date('w'))*24*3600);
```

Then within my pdo query i have:

```
$query = " 
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        bookings as bb 
    INNER JOIN 
        reservation as br ON bb.booking_id=br.bookings_id
    INNER JOIN 
        cars as bc ON br.car_id=bc.car_id 
    WHERE 
        payment_success=1 AND 
        is_block=false AND 
        is_deleted=0 AND
        DATE_FORMAT(start_date, '%d-%m-%Y') 
        BETWEEN '".$week_start."' AND '".$week_end."'
"; 

try { 
    $stmt = DB::get()->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute(); 

    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
}  
catch(PDOException $ex) { 
    die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); 
} 

foreach($rows as $row):
    $row['booking_id'] etc...
endforeach;
```

The problem is i am not getting any rows to show up in the output despite having multiple bookings which have a start date within this week

Comment: echo $query. Then paste that sql directly into the DB to test it. I suspect your date format is incorrect. If it works directly with the db, paste the complete query here so we can examine.

Comment: How do you determine that no rows are returned? What is the output of `var_dump($rows);` ?

Comment: Mike - using your snippet i still get nothing coming out in the output, i have it as: – foreach($rows as $row):
    $html .= var_dump($rows);
   endforeach;
  
   return $html;

Comment: @odd_duck I didn't mean in your `foreach` loop :P Anyway try @Sammitch's answer and see what you get.

Comment: Also be sure to put an @ before my name if you want it to notify me of your reply.

Comment: @Mike thanks, still new to how this works! Sammitch's answer works, though the client is requesting that the dates are in the format of d-m-Y rather than Y-m-d. How can i go about formatting it this way?

Comment: The easiest way is to use a `DateTime` object and `format()` it however you want. For the query, use `Y-m-d`. Use whatever you want for everything else.

Comment: You are using PDO and calling prepare...why aren't you using prepared statements properly?  Using string concatenation for your query is undoing all the security benefits of PDO!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DATE_FORMAT()` returns a string, not a date. Passing 3 string arguments to `BETWEEN`... who knows what that is going to return.

To un-ass-backwards your code, use:

```
$week_start = date('Y-m-d',time()+( 1 - date('w'))*24*3600);  
$week_end =  date('Y-m-d',time()+( 7 - date('w'))*24*3600);
```

to format your dates in the way mySQL expects, and:

```
WHERE 
  start_date BETWEEN '".$week_start."' AND '".$week_end."'
```

in the query.

Or if you would prefer an object-oriented approach, do something like this:

```
$week_start = new DateTime; 
$week_end = new DateTime;
$week_start->setTimestamp(time()+( 1 - date('w'))*24*3600)); 
$week_end->setTimestamp(time()+( 7 - date('w'))*24*3600);
```

Then in your query do:

```
WHERE 
  start_date 
      BETWEEN '".$week_start->format('Y-m-d')."'
      AND '".$week_end->format('Y-m-d')."'
```

Then for everything else, you can echo the format how you wish:

```
echo $date->format('d-m-Y'); // etc
```

Comment: Thanks @Sammitch! This works perfectly now, though the client is requesting that the dates are in the format of d-m-Y rather than Y-m-d. How can i go about formatting it this way?

Comment: @Sammitch, hope you don't mind I significantly edited your post.