# PDO Query row from mysql if date saved is more than 1 year

Tags: php, mysql, date, pdo

I know there must be 100 different examples of searching by date but they aren't working and I am unable to figure out the code!  I have a table that saves a name and a future date among other things. The date is saved by the user and is in a varchar field as mm-dd-YYYY although I can change that if needed. (suggestions appreciated).

I need to query the usernames based on the date to send out reminder emails. Example is sending an email to those that are more than 1 year from the date they saved. All I have so far is selecting everything and trying to filter the dates but it's a mess and I just erased it all and wrote this question.  Can anyone help?

Right now I have

```
$date = date('m-d-Y');

$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE thedate > 1year FROM $date"
    // I know this is horribly wrong

// $query_params = array( ':username' => $email );

        try {
            // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
            $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
            $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
        }
            catch (PDOException $ex) {

        }

        $rows = $stmt->fetchALL();
        foreach ($rows as $row) {

        $username = $row['username'];

}
```

There might be 5 names or 500 so I need to get it filtered from the database first before attaching them to emails.  Thanks!

Comment: `"but they aren't working"` - show us *at least one* you have seen. And then try to explain where did you get that "from now()"

Comment: Examples found are comparing two dates. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099187/pdo-php-find-all-rows-between-2-dates-shows-blank?rq=1 Doesn't work for my applications. Also examples if a date is greater than today or now.  I need to compare to the date saved.

Comment: make your date YYYY-MM-DD format and follow **regular SQL syntax** instead of inventing your own - and everything will work

Comment: I will change the date format, thank you.  My reason for posting the question is to ask what the correct syntax is for this?  I know it's not > 1 year but that is where I am stuck.

Comment: The very linked question shows you one of the possible ways. WHY on the earth you don't want to use it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be best to change the type in the database but you can filter them out in PHP.

You can do it by creating the time 1-year out and then comparing each row to the time. It does not exactly scale well but it will filter the names.

It would look like:

```
$query = "SELECT username,thedate FROM users WHERE thedate > 1year From now()";
// I know this is horribly wrong

// $query_params = array( ':username' => $email );

try {
    // These two statements run the query against your database table. 
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {

}

$rows = $stmt->fetchALL();
$time = strtotime("+1 year"); // Create the day 1 year out
$result = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    // If the database date is greater than 1-year out, add it to the result array
    if ($time < strtotime($row['thedate']))
        $result[] = $row;
}
```

If you change the column type you can also create the parameter and use the mysql function `FROM_UNIXTIME` in the where clause:

```
$oneyearahead = strtotime("+1 year");
$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE thedate > FROM_UNIXTIME($oneyearahead)";
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. After changing the database to save the date as Y-m-d I could perform the search using your last section.                   

$date = date("Y-m-d");
$oneyearahead = strtotime('+1 year', $date);

$query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE thedate > FROM_UNIXTIME($oneyearahead)";

Thanks again.